# Can't fix this CORS issue, Am I missing something here?

Tags: reactjs, express, file-upload, fetch, react-fullstack

I am trying to deploy this MERN stack app,It's a blog app, just for learning reasons, backend on heroku and front end on Netlify. So fat when I run things on my local machine it works just fine. However After de[ploying, I am running into an issue with the create route in the app, Each time I click create post, I get a cors error, It seems to be only exclusive to the post route ending in "/post".

***taken from back end index.js***

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', "https://blogsfe.netlify.app/","https://blogsfe.netlify.app"],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200, 
    credentials: true
  };
```

*//Please ignore some of the commented out lines inside the code, they are there just to remind of my last step or of other alternative options*

```
app.use(cors());
// 'https://blogsfe.netlify.app
// app.use(cors({credentials:true, origin:["https://blogsfe.netlify.app","http://localhost:3000"]}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser())
```

***How I am sending the request from the front end***

```
async function createNewPost(e){
    const data = new FormData();
    data.set("title", title);
    data.set("summary", summary);
    data.set("content", content);
    data.set("file", files[0] )
    // console.log(files)
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(BASEURL)
    const response = await fetch(`${BASEURL}/post`,{
        method:"POST",
        body: data,
        mode:"no-cors",
        credentials: 'include',

    })
    console.log(response,"respos")

    if(response.ok){
        console.log("esha")
        setRedirect(true)
    } else{
        console.log("7ah")
    }
    
    if(redirect === true){
     return (<Navigate to={"/login"} />)
    }
    // console.log(redirect)

    // console.log(await response.json())
}
```

***my backend route and controller function below***

```
 app.post("/post",uploadMiddleware.single("file"), async(req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.cookies),"reqreq"
    const {originalname, path} = req.file;

    const parts = originalname.split(".")
    const ext = parts[parts.length -1];
    const newPath = path+"."+ext
    // console.log(newPath,"newpath")
    fs.renameSync(path, newPath)
    const {token} = req.cookies;
    console.log(token,"token")
    console.log(req.body,"body")
    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info)=>{
        if(err) throw err;

        const{title, summary, content} = req.body;
        const postDoc = await Post.create({
            title,
            summary,
            content,
            cover: newPath,
            author: info.id
        })
    
        // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

        res.json(postDoc)
      
    })
```

})